# Goodwins "proof" and space time

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, history, space-expansion

I read about Goodwin's "proof" that $\pi = 3.20$, it's BS and I know that. What I am wondering is whether his technique may have stumbled on something ( a warped space) years before Einstein. So I guess my question is this:

Is it possible that somewhere in the universe (say the vicinity of a neutron star) where (due to the warped space) the ratio of the circumference to the radius is measured as something other than 3.14...?

Following from that, is it possible that we only measure $\pi$ as 3.14... because of the way *our* local space time is curved by the earth?

Comment: My gut feel is that it is out of the question that Goodwin was thinking anything along these lines. If he were doing so with considered thought, there's a fairly good chance that he would have cited people like William Clifford, Bernhard Riemann, C. F. Gauss, Henri Poincare who were thinking along these lines. Actually I am wondering whether the whole $\pi = 3.2$ thing was partly a misguided attempt to forestall disputes in commerce about volumes and areas and such like by deeming, *for the purposes of certain commercial transactions*, $\pi$ would be such and such a convenient value.

Answer (score 8):

> I read about Goodwin's "proof" that π = 3.20... Its BS and I know that. What I am wondering is whether his technique may have stumbled on something ( a warped space) years before Einstein.

In short, no. Slightly longer, noooo....

Notably, even if Goodwin made some coherent sense (and he did not), doing this before Einstein is not a significant achievement, because much of mathematics of curved manifolds was already formulated both before Einstein and before this silliness. The discovery of non-Euclidean geometries happened about seven decades prior to this, and perhaps even longer depending on how one counts priority of discovery.

> SO I guess my question Is this. Is it possible that somewhere in the universe (say the vicinity of a neutron star) where (due to the warped space) the ratio of the circumference to the radius is measured as something other than 3.14...

Yes, this will be generally the case, although one has to be careful about how one defines 'circle' in this context (spacelike geodesic distance will do for small radii).

> Following from that, is it possible that we only measure π as 3.14... because of the way OUR local space time is curved by the earth?

No, it's not possible because we don't measure $\pi$ at all; rather, we define it in reference to Euclidean geometry, which is flat. However, Euclidean geometry probably has intuitive simplicity for humans because it closely matches the geometry of space in our environment.

Comment: $\pi = (\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} dx)^2$. I don't see any references to geometry :)

Comment: @lionelbrits In order to calculate the integral squared you introduce **flat** **polar** coordinates, in which you can perform the integration.

Comment: @Neuneck, that is certainly one way. There are [others, like this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188241/how-to-prove-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2-without-changi)

Comment: @lionelbrits you are right, but your point is semantic.  The value of that integral doesn't change, the ratio of radius to circumference will however. Which one you choose to call $pi$ is what matters. (Although everyone chooses your one)

Answer (score 0):

To add to [Stan Liou's point](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/89244/26076):

> No, it's not possible because we don't measure $\pi$ at all; rather, we define it in reference to Euclidean geometry, which is flat. However, Euclidean geometry probably has intuitive simplicity for humans because it closely matches the geometry of space in our environment.

Here's one way of understanding explicitly what Stan is talking about. We *define* for the purposes of *calculating* $\pi$ a 1-sphere (a circle) to be the set of points with position vectors $\vec{r} = \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\end{array}\right)$ such that $\left<\vec{r},\,\vec{r}\right>=x^2+y^2=1$; so *we have used Pythagoras's theorem and are tacitly assuming the spatial part of the metric tensor is diagonal and with constant co-efficients (the first fundamental form is ${\rm d}\,s^2 = {\rm d}\,x^2 + {\rm d}\,y^2$)*. So we are, in turn, assuming *all* of Euclid's axioms, including the parallel postulate.

Once we have done this, find the equation of motion of a point $\vec{r}(t) = \left(\begin{array}{c}x(t)\\y(t)\end{array}\right)$ constrained to the circle is defined by ${\rm d}_t \left<\vec{r},\,\vec{r}\right> = 0$, whence $\left<{\rm d}_t \vec{r}(t),\,\vec{r}(t)\right> = 0$,  whence (with a little fiddling):

$${\rm d}_t \left(\begin{array}{c}x(t)\\y(t)\end{array}\right) = v(t) \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{c}x(t)\\y(t)\end{array}\right)$$

where $v(t) = \sqrt{\dot{x}^2+\dot{y}^2}$. We take, for simplicity, $v(t) = 1$ so that we immediately have, by the universal convergence of the matrix exponential (the path begins at the point $x=1,y=0$ at time $t=0$):

$$\left(\begin{array}{c}\cos t \\\sin t\end{array}\right) \stackrel{def}{=} \exp\left[\left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)\,t\right]\left(\begin{array}{c}1\\0\end{array}\right)$$

and the universally and uniformly convergent Taylor series for $\cos$ and $\sin$ follow: to do this, expand the universally convergent $\exp$ series then simplify it with the knowledge that $i^2 =-1$ where $i= \left(\begin{array}{cc}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)$. It is from these Taylor series that various series expressions for $\pi$ are found: for our purposes we can define $\cos (\pi/2) = 0$: we say by definition that the pathlength a fourth the way around the circle is $\pi / 2$, and then ask a friendly computer to help us solve $\cos (\pi/2) = 0$ numerically as accurately as we like with arbitrary precision arithmetic (as one can do in Mathematica, or in one's own code).

So you see that the number we call $\pi$ follows from a particular *set of axioms for geometry*, and is *independent of whether or not those axioms truly model the space around us*.

See a pretty discussion of all this in the first chapter of R. Penrose "The Road to Reality" and also in Chapter 22 "Algebra" of the first volume of the "Feynman Lectures on Physics".

My gut feel is that it is out of the question that Goodwin was thinking anything along these lines. If he were doing so with considered thought, there's a fairly good chance that he would have cited people like William Clifford, Bernhard Riemann, Carl Friedrich Gauss, Henri Poincaré who were thinking along these lines. Actually I am wondering whether the whole $\pi=3.2$  thing was partly a misguided attempt to forestall disputes in commerce about volumes and areas and such like by deeming, for the purposes of certain commercial transactions, $\pi$ would be such and such a convenient value. Of course Goodwin was crazy, but there may have been some half sensible (for the time, when accurate measurement was not as cheap as today) reasons why one might want to legislate a value for commercial transactions.